# Mongodb query variable number of search terms

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to design a query based on documents containing an array of metadata.

book = {
    title : String,
    metaData : [String]
}

To find the desired books I have another search string array containing multiple metadata terms.  The length of the array can be variable in the number of metadata search terms present.  How can I query to find only books that contain all the specified metadata search terms?

Example:

book1 - nature, trees, insects, fog, music
book2 - music, art, sports

Search using metadata of [music, sports] would yield book2.

How can I most efficiently design this query?  Can I do this and avoid a nested query? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the `$all` operator.

From the docs:

> If, instead, you wish to find an array that contains both the elements "red" and "blank", without regard to order or other elements in the array, use the $all operator:
>
> `db.inventory.find( { tags: { $all: ["red", "blank"] } } )`

[MongoDB CRUD Operations: Query an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$all` to get all the documents containing the given metadata strings.

Try:

```
let given_metadata_array = ["music", "sports"];

db.book.find({
    metadata : {$all : given_metadata_array}
})
```

Read more about [$all official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all) for detailed information.